# Which logs will Plesk deal with?

Tags: centos, logging, vps

I'm about to move to a VPS server running CentOS 6 and the latest version of Plesk. I've been told to look into logs and log rotation - which I know Plesk supports - but it has been mentioned that Linux may have several logs that are not covered by it, for instance the mail log and the server access log.

So really, what I'd like to know is which logs won't be covered by Plesk? But also is there something better I should use/install to manage all the logs?

Thanks in advance. By the way, you may have guessed but I'm completely new to VPS.

Comment: Why constrain yourself to what is supported by plesk?  It is a crutch.

Comment: @FalconMomot Well Plesk is the only CP offered by the provider I want to go with, but I don't suppose I have to use Plesk to manage the logs... What do you suggest?

Comment: @Andy The suggestion you're likely to get around here is "Don't use the control panels, they're terrible". Generally questions about the **use** of cPanel/Plesk type "manage it for you" tools are off-topic on server fault ([we'll deal with setting them up and administering them](http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/3425) - i.e. what your provider does - but the end-user operation of the software is between you and your provider.)

Comment: @voretaq7 Ok, I was getting that general feeling around here but seeing as though I'll be 'diving in head first with no experience' so to speak, it's only best if I used Plesk for the time being. I'll gradually try and rely on it less but at the minute, it's going to do more good than harm. Just a note about the reason this topic was put on hold though - this isn't a situation in a home setting really! I'll be hosting a company website on the VPS so it's important I get everything right

Comment: @Andy Yeah the close reason isn't really correct - we don't have an appropriate close reason for Plesk questions ("Home Setting" was the one most people voted for) -- [We're working on that though](http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/5605/new-close-reasons-proposals-july-2013)

Comment: @voretaq7 Fair enough. Well, at least I have the answer to my question so I'm not too fused but for future reference, is there a StackExchange site where I can ask such questions regarding Plesk (or any control panel)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plesk uses own logrotate binary(check **rpm -qa | grep logrotate**), which uses following config **/usr/local/psa/etc/logrotate.conf** and configs from **/usr/local/psa/etc/logrotate.d/**

All other logs are not covered.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Would it be possible to 'tell' Plesk to cover all the other logs, or would I need to use some other management tool for that (if so, what can I use)?

Comment: Well, I think it's convenient to use Plesk's logrotate(Because it's already installed and it's industrial standard for linux). You can create your own config in /usr/local/psa/etc/logrotate.d/ which will be used together with plesk's log rotation.

Comment: Ok thank you for your help, the information you've provided is very useful and exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score -2):

[link](http://kb.parallels.com/en/111283) I would guess you can have it show the ones listed in the link

Comment: We really do prefer that answers contain content not pointers to content. Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Although, it doesn't really answer the question anyway. You "would guess"... So you don't actually know?

Comment: Yes, I would guess.  I don't know what your system is running so of course I can't tell you for sure. See which you want and do like Oleg suggests.